# Smooth transition from launch image to main view

Tags: iphone, transition, launch

Is it possible to implement a smooth transition when the app loads, from the launch image to the first view?

The default behavior is on/off, with an immediate change: the launch image appears, then it instantaneously disappears to let the main view controller take place. I'd like to implement some fading or zooming in or out.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's no framework support, but you can get that result if you do it yourself, manually. Depending on what your launch image is, and what your UI looks like, you can do it in different ways, but basically: make your first view controller load and display your default.png image in an image view when it loads up. Then animate a fade out of that image to reveal your actual UI.

Comment: Seems to be a clean and simple solution!

Answer (score 7):

Modified Dancreek's answer to do it all in AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I like this because the code is guaranteed to only run at app start, and it's not polluting any of the view controllers.

It's very simple:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // set up your root view and stuff....

    //.....(do whatever else you need to do)...

    // show the main window, overlay with splash screen + alpha dissolve...

        UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:splashScreen];        
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;}
                     completion:(void (^)(BOOL)) ^{
                             [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                     }
    ];
}
```

Comment: I had to change  your addSubview line to this:
    [self.window addSubview:splashScreen]; 

but it worked great

Comment: @joekutner Yeah, in hindsight it's a more general solution to add the splash directly to the window. That will always work. What I did worked for me, but it depends on your initial view setup. I put your solution in the answer, it's better ;)

Comment: Even better, create a separate UIWindow just for your splash image view, and set its window level above the main window.  This ensures the image will stay on top, even if other parts of your initialization code add additional subviews to the mainwindow later.

Answer (score 2):

You are in luck.  I just did this a few min ago. You need a splash screen.  An image on your view that is exactly the same as your default image that the device loads.  Then in your app have it dismiss with a fade animation called from the viewDidAppear function

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSelector:@selector(killSplashScreen) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}

- (void)killSplashScreen {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;} completion:NULL];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We often use something called "splashView" to do this. It was written by Shannon Applecline and available under the CC license. You will have to do some Googling to find it.

```
//
//  splashView.h
//  version 1.1
//
//  Created by Shannon Appelcline on 5/22/09.
//  Copyright 2009 Skotos Tech Inc.
//
//  Licensed Under Creative Commons Attribution 3.0:
//  http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0/
//  You may freely use this class, provided that you maintain these attribute comments
//
//  Visit our iPhone blog: http://iphoneinaction.manning.com
//
```