# how to add animation on the first view of my project

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Smooth transition from launch image to main view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310274/smooth-transition-from-launch-image-to-main-view)

I have application let us assume hello world and i need to do fadein animation on the hello world view after the app splash screen disappear , how i can implement this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HelloViewController you need to put this code in the ViewDidAppear delegate method like so

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
    [self.view setAlpha:0.0];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

You can fade the view in by setting its alpha to 0 and then adding it to the view of your initial view controller

```
[myViewController addSubview:myNewView];
```

Then you can just call

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^(void){
    [myNewView setAlpha:1.0];
    }];
}
```