# Transition from default@2x.png to MainView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am relatively new to Objective-C and iOS development in general, and would appreciate any help and guidance with my problem.

I have written my first app, which is a 'Utility' app with a main and flip view. The app works as expected both on the simulator and my iPhone. However, there is a noticeable and abrupt change from the Default.png image to my main view.

I have followed n13's suggested code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918650/1324822, however, all I get is the main view, followed by a fade to black.

My code, within the AppDelegate.m file is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{   
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

// set up your root view and stuff....
//.....(do whatever else you need to do)...

// show the main window, overlay with splash screen + alpha dissolve...
UIImageView *splashScreen = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
[self.window addSubview:splashScreen];        
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{splashScreen.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL)) ^{
                     [splashScreen removeFromSuperview];
                 }
 ];
return YES;
 }
```

I will admit that I am 'winging' this part of my project, though I am very keen to understand what is causing the issue, and how to resolve it. I expect I need to specify my mainView somewhere above, perhaps initialise it as commented, but I am unsure how to do this given that without the transition the only requirement is to set `return YES;`.

If it helps, this is a storyboard project. I am running Xcode 4.3.3.

Thanks again.

Comment: If you're using storyboard, why don't you just use a drag and drop segue? I'd advise you to try writing as little code as possible if you're new to objective-c.

Comment: Will this allow the me to create the fade in transition above? I do want to write the code, but more importantly, understand it.

Comment: Yes, you can set the type of transition

Comment: Sorry, to be a pain, can you explain how I would drag and drop segue? Do I do that in the storyboard directly?

Comment: You control-drag from one view to another view

Comment: But will this work if I am wanting to transition from the default launch image (Default@2x.png) to my main View?

Comment: I'm confused about what you mean by transition from an image... Do you have a viewcontroller with an image in it?

Comment: Yes. My Main View Controller has a ImageView which contains Background.png I have also set a Default@2x.png. When the app launches, there is an abrupt change from the Default@2x.png image to my Main View Controller. And what I would like to do is fade from the former to the latter.

Comment: Are these both in storyboard?

Comment: My launch image has been defined in the project summary, if that's what you're asking (thanks for your continued assistance).

Comment: If you can see them both in the storyboard, just do the control-drag thing. If you can't, post a screencap or something so I can better understand your setup.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do splash screens:

I don't put it into the App Delegate, instead on the first screen that is viewed. All you need is two instance variables in your rootViewController, first is UIView *black and the second is UIImageView *splash. Then :

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

    self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    black = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
    black.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];


    splash = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];

    UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [splash addSubview:indicator];
    indicator.center = CGPointMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width/2, 455);

    [indicator startAnimating];
    //the indicator part is arbitrary, of course

    splash.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"];

    [self.view addSubview:black];
    [self.view addSubview:splash];

});


}
```

Then:

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {

static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{



    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 delay:2 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        splash.alpha=0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [splash removeFromSuperview];

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.45 delay:0.2 options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            black.alpha = 0; 
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            [black removeFromSuperview];
            black = nil;
            splash = nil;
            self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        }];
    }];

});


}
```

I have not tested this code with apps that have navigation controllers or tab view controllers but it works like a charm with regular view controllers.